# Can you explain a grammar of this sentence please

Tags: grammar

> Yeah, yeah. Microsoft would have been willing to buy it, too. . . . I don't know for $19 billion, but the company's extremely valuable.

Full Article is [here](http://www.rollingstone.com/culture/news/bill-gates-the-rolling-stone-interview-20140313#ixzz2vvokJBkD).

From the context I can understand that Microsoft wanted to buy WhatsApp before Facebook did, but I can't understand the grammar. Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: "I don't know for $19 billion, but the company's extremely valuable." is conversational, it's not a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: I was mainly concern the first part of the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

A chunk of the second sentence has been elided. It is more than one would expect in a work of scholarship, but clearly this was no 'work of scholarship'.

'I don't know (if they would have been willing to buy it) for $19 billion...'

I think I would have gone part way, and said 'I don't know if they would have paid $19 billion...'

Comment: 'I don't know (if **we** would have been willing to buy it) for $19 billion'

Comment: I can't understand the grammar of *... would have been willing ...*.

Comment: @TIKSN For the '*would have been* (verb continuous/ gerund)' construction, we can ask on [ell.se]

Comment: It is more about usage rather than learning.